# Reading a pl Knowledge Base in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Hello I am trying to read a propositional logic Knowledge Base from a txt file using the java scanner class. The Knowledge Base.txt is :

```
~B11
W44
~B11|P12|P21
~P12|B11
~P21|B11
~B21|P11|P22|P31
 B21|~P11
 B21|~P22
 B21|~P31
~B34|W24|W33|W44
 B34|~W24
 B34|~W33
 B34|~W44
```

My code is :

```
public static void choice1()
{
    //Contains the CNFsubclauses of the KB
    ArrayList<CNFSubClause> sbList = new ArrayList<>();

    //Read the KB from the text file
    try {
        System.out.print("Reading Knowledge Base from file... ");   


        File file = new File("Knowledge Base.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        //Read the CNFSubClauses from the txt file and store them in an ArrayList(sbList)
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {              
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            CNFSubClause sb = new CNFSubClause();
            String[] literalsStrings = line.split("|");
            boolean neg = false;
            String name = null;

            for(int i = 0; i<=literalsStrings.length; i++){
               if(literalsStrings[i].charAt(0)=='~'){
                   neg = false;
                   name = literalsStrings[i];
                   Literal lit = new Literal(name, neg);
                   sb.getLiterals().add(lit);
                   sbList.add(sb);
                   lit.print();
                }
               else{
                   neg = true;
                   name = literalsStrings[i];
                   Literal lit = new Literal(name, neg);
                   sb.getLiterals().add(lit);
                   sbList.add(sb);
                   lit.print();
               }
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    CNFClause KB = new CNFClause();


    //Store the CNFSubClauses of sbList in a CNFClause KB
    for(CNFSubClause sb : sbList){
        KB.getSubclauses().add(sb);          
    }
```

Literal represent a literal, a variable.
A CNFSubClause in turn consists of a disjunction of literals.
A CNFClause consists of a conjunction of CNFSubClauses.

So when I am running the code it just print the follow:

```
Reading Knowledge Base from file... ~
NOT_B
NOT_1
NOT_1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
----------------------------------------------------

at Main.choice1(Main.java:45)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Comment: `split` method takes a regex, and `|` is a regex keyword/literal. you need to escape it: `split("\\|")`.

Comment: Thanks its solved but for some reason it is just reading the  first line of the file.